# "Matrix" multiplication of Dirac delta distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Forgive me if I am not very rigorous, part of the following question is to hopefully clear up any inconsistencies coming from my lack of rigor. In any case I will try to make things clear enough that you at least understand what I am trying to ask.

I would like to consider a type of matrix multiplication between distributions $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$, with $x,y\in S$, defined as
$$\big(M*N\big)(x,y)=\int_Sdz\,M(x,z)N(z,y)$$
More specifically, I'd like to consider the matrix multiplication between $f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-y)$ and $g(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-y)$, with $S=\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. I seem to be getting different answers depending on how I evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\,\Big(f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-z)\Big)g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\delta (z-y)=f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz\,\delta (x-z)g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\delta (z-y)\Big)=f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(g(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta(x-y)\Big). \tag{1}$$
The right hand side is obtained by using the definition of the first dirac delta distribution in the integrand. If I instead apply the definition to the second dirac delta distribution, I find
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \,dz\Big(f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-z)\Big)g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\delta (z-y)=-f(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz\,\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big(g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-z)\Big)\delta (z-y)=-f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big(g(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-y)\Big). \tag{2}$$

These two expression don't appear to be equal. Are they equal? And if not, what went wrong?

Comment: They should be equal.  In both results, *both* $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ should be in the derivative.  You should not have the minus sign in your second result.  I know it seems strange, but it is an oddity of the $\delta$ function.

Comment: @bob.sacamento thanks for the comment. Did I do either of the calculations incorrectly?

Comment: In your first calculation, remember that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ only acts on the first $\delta.$ It does not act on $g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\delta(z-y),$ not even after replacing $z$ with $x$.

Comment: As you probably already know, there cannot be a good general sense for the composition of the two two-variable distributions. By Schwartz' Kernel theorem, all maps from test functions to distributions (for example) are given by such "kernels", but then there's the obvious general problem of composition (without further conditions), since the image of the first-applied operator may easily fall outside the domain of the second. But, of course, specific examples (and/or specific hypotheses) can skirt this problem. Do you really want a very-general version?

Comment: @md2perpe Why is that? I added another step to the calculation that should clarify how I arrived at my answers, is there something wrong with what I did?

Comment: @paulgarrett What I am interested in are distributions with point-like support, do these behave nicely under composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: One may show that the RHS of OP's eqs. (1) & (2) are equal by using the following 2 identities
$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\delta(x-y)~=~0, \tag{A}$$
and
$$ \left(g(x)-g(y)\right)\delta(x-y)~=~0, \tag{B}$$
where $g$ is a test function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my 2 a.m. take on the integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, \left( f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\delta (x-z) \right) \left( g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\delta(z-y) \right)
\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, f(x) \, \delta'(x-z) \, g(z) \, \delta'(z-y)
\\
= f(x) \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, \delta'(x-z) \, g(z) \, \delta'(z-y)
\\
= -f(x) \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left( \delta'(x-z) \, g(z) \right) \, \delta(z-y)
\\
= -f(x) \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \, \left( -\delta''(x-z) \, g(z) + \delta'(x-z)\,g'(z) \right) \, \delta(z-y)
\\
= -f(x) \left( -\delta''(x-y) \, g(y) + \delta'(x-y) \, g'(y) \right)
\\
= f(x) \, \delta''(x-y) \, g(y) - f(x) \, \delta'(x-y) \, g'(y)
$$

Comment: It looks like you got the same answer as my second attempt (after switching the y derivative acting on the delta to be an x derivative). Is there something wrong with my first attempt?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that can be said about "integral operators" of the form $Tf(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} k(x-y)\,f(y)\;dy$, where $k$ is meets a suitable smoothness condition away from $0$, and its Fourier transform (e.g.) has suitable decay. These are "singular integral operators of convolution type", for a search-able key-phrase.

With suitable tweaks of the conditions on the kernel, these give bounded operators $L^p\to L^p$, and has other good/interesting features.

The prototype is the Hilbert transform, with $k(x)=1/x$. This already illustrates the point that the "integral" defining the transform cannot *quite* be a literal integral, but must be a principal value version of the integral. The simplest $n$-dimensional analogue is the Riesz transforms, with $k(x)=x_i/|x|^{n+1}$. On $\mathbb R^2$, for $m=1,2,3,\ldots$, $k((x,y))=(x\pm iy)^m/(x^2+y^2)^{{m\over 2}+1}$ gives another family of this sort.

For kernels $K(x,y)$ not of the form $k(x-y)$, the key-phrase "Calderon-Zygmund kernel/operator" is a good search-phrase.